# Unable to update MySQL with PHP

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm making an android app using MySQL and PHP for registration, and my MySQL database is not updating. I am getting to the php methods, but am not successfully updating the table. Here is the important snippet of java code:

```
public void updateGroupName() {
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText groupName = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.group);
                final String name = groupName.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("Name of group is: " + name);
                updateUser(name);
                       System.out.println("Trying to update user group");
                        if (!name.isEmpty()) {

                            //add to sqlite database
                            updateUser(name);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Please enter your details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                        String tag_string_req = "req_update";

                        //showDialog();

                        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                                AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Update Response: " + response.toString());
                                //hideDialog();

                                try {
                                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                                    if (!error) {
                                        System.out.println("User group successfully updated in mysql");
                                        // User successfully stored in MySQL
                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println("The use group failed to update");
                                        // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                                        // message
                                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Update Error: " + error.getMessage());
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                hideDialog();
                            }
                        }) {
                            String email = db.getUserDetails().get("email");
                            @Override
                            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                                System.out.println("trying to return params");
                                // Posting params to register url
                                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                                params.put("tag", "update");
                                params.put("user_group", name);
                                params.put("email", email);
                                return params;
                            }
                        };
                        System.out.println("updating group to mysql database");
                        // Adding request to request queue
                        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
//                System.out.println("here1");
//                System.out.println("user group: " + db.getUserDetails().get("user_group"));
                dialog.dismiss();
                    }
        });
        //System.out.println("here2");
    }
```

Here are the important portions of my PHP code:

```
else if ($tag == "update") {
        $user_group = $_POST['user_group'];
        $uid = $_POST['email'];
        //update user
        $user = $db->updateUser($user_group, $email);
        if ($user) {
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["user_group"] = ["user"]["user_group"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo "The update User function was called and a user was returned";
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Updating user group";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }

public function updateUser($user_group, $email) {
        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET user_group = '$user_group' WHERE email = '$email'");
        if ($result) {
            // get user details 
            $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
            // return user details
            return mysql_fetch_array($result);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: mysql update query does not set mysql_insert_id(). Use mysqli as mysql is deprecated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean? Is mysqli a function?

Comment: mysql_insert_id() is working fine for my register and login functions.

Comment: on insert operation this mysql_insert_id() function do returns the last inserted id by for update it does not.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php for deprecation explaination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `$email` to your method `updateUser` but the email address is stored in `$uid`.

Please change

```
$user = $db->updateUser($user_group, $email);
```

to

```
$user = $db->updateUser($user_group, $uid);
```

Comment: What do you mean the email address is stored in $uid? Why can't I pass in a parameter like $email- it is working when I pass it into my other functions such as register and login.

Comment: You are storing the mail address in `$uid`: `$uid = $_POST['email'];` In your answer there is no part where `$email` is initialized. That's the reason why I told you to use `$uid` instead of `$email` ;-)

Comment: I mean `In your question ...` instead of `In your answer ...`.